# Build Azure Pipeline by last commit

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have pipelines which trigger on each commit and create new build. Usually we make many commits at one time and there collect many builds. Can I configure my pipeline to trigger by last commit or wait 60 seconds for new commit to create build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Batch changes while a build is in progress" in 'Triggers' Azure Pipelines to run build for first and last commit or include '***NO_CI***' in the commit message or description of the HEAD commit.